# How can I change the name an executable presents itself to the system

Tags: symlink, kill

Forgot to mention, running on Suse Tumbleweed, Desktop is KDE Plasma.

I have in my `bin` directory a symbolic link to `mpv`,

```
$ ls -l bin/Play 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 boffi users 12 Feb 11 12:33 bin/Play -> /usr/bin/mpv
```

and I have a script that calls `Play` to, ehm, play a random music file

```
$ cat bin/play_alarm 
#! /usr/bin/bash

files=($(find $HOME/Music/$1 -type f))
n_files=${#files[@]}
index=$(($RANDOM%$n_files))
file=${files[$index]}
body=$(
  echo $file | sed -E '
    s./home/boffi/Music/..
    s./[01][0-9]_./.
    s/\..*$//
    s./. → .g
    s._. .g
    s| → ([^→]+)$| → <b>\1</b>|')
notify-send -u low -a "The Alarm Player" --expire-time=10000 Playing "$body" &
Play --no-video --no-terminal ${files[$index]}
```

In my understanding, I could kill `mpv`, that specific issue of `mpv`, using the name `Play`, but

```
$ bin/play_alarm & sleep 10 ; killall Play ; sleep 2 ; killall mpv
[1] 1385
Play: no process found
$ Terminated

[1]+  Exit 143                bin/play_alarm
$
```

My problem is "*How can I change the name an executable presents itself to the system*". Of course I'm doing something wrong, or I have a serious misunderstanding.

**Addendum** Before you ask, if I start `play_alarm` from the command line I can kill it using `killall play_alarm` but tipically `play_alarm` is started by a Plasma desklet, and then

1. `killall play_alarm` does not work,
2. `killall Play` does not work,
3. `killall mpv` kills the alarm and every `mpv` issue that is running.

**PS** Should you suggest saving PIDs in temporary files, I'd prefer not to, but if everything else fails...

Comment: So, constructive feedback: you clearly need to find a better way than `killall` if you need something to stop that potentially runs in parallel on your computer, and any answer to your question won't change that.

Comment: I think a hardlink would do it.

Comment: Note that I just tried this: `ln -s /usr/bin/sleep mysleep; ./mysleep 1000 &`, then, `killall sleep` does *not* kill `mysleep`, but `killall mysleep` does. So, the opposite of what you are describing! And that is well-reflected in `/proc/{PID of mysleep as started above/cmdline` and in `[…]/stat`, which are the two files that `killall` consults for every process to decide whether to kill it.

Comment: What I'm wondering here, is if `mpv` does something odd and overwrites the name it was originally given, or if running that as a desklet does something odd. What does `ps` show for the processes in each case? Actually, I think `killall` and `pgrep` (without `-f`) look at the name field in the first line of `/proc/PID/status` (which isn't what `ps` shows if you do e.g. `(exec -a lion /bin/cat)`)

Comment: @ilkkachu You're RIGHT, it's `mpv` that changes back its name to `mpv`. I'll try to open an issue, maybe.

Comment: https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/13469

Comment: github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/13469 ⇒ "It's not a bug it's a feature"

Comment: What is the goal?  How do `play_alarm` and `Play` interoperate?  I don't see an outcome of any purpose.  If there was a complete picture, there may be a whole other angle of attack.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with `sleep` and have the following observation:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/sleep  slapen
./slapen 900 &
```

`ps -ef | grep slapen` then gives:

```
ljm      2623965 2534378  0 16:53 pts/5    00:00:00 ./slapen 900
ljm      2623968 2534378  0 16:54 pts/5    00:00:00 grep slapen
```

The name of the process is therefore `slapen` instead of `sleep` as you suggest.

```
pkill slapen
```

gives:

```
[1]+  Terminated              ./slapen 900
```

which is what you seem to need.

Answer (score -1):

To clarify my comments under my question,

```
$ ls -l ~/bin/Play
lrwxrwxrwx 1 boffi users 12 Feb 11 12:33 /home/boffi/bin/Play -> /usr/bin/mpv
$ Play --no-terminal Music/Aldous_Harding/Party/06_Horizon.opus & sleep 3 ; ps
[1] 16098
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
11599 pts/4    00:00:00 bash
16098 pts/4    00:00:00 mpv
16121 pts/4    00:00:00 ps
$
```

On the other hand

```
$ ls ~/bin/mysleep /home/boffi/bin/mysleep
$ mysleep 10 & ps 
[1] 22546
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
11599 pts/4    00:00:00 bash
22546 pts/4    00:00:00 mysleep
22547 pts/4    00:00:00 ps
$
```

so that we may conclude that for some reason, or even without any reason, `mpv` changes back its name to `mpv`.

Comment: When you're adding information, please edit your question instead of putting it in an answer. It is also interesting that the `ls` of `mysleep` dir not return anything. If user accounts are set up in the usual fashion I would expect `~/bin` and `/home/boffi/bin` to point to the same directory.

Comment: @doneal24 IMO the info I've posted here answers my question: I cannot do what I want to do (that is what I've done for 30+ years with other programs) because Mpv won't cooperate. If you disagree, please flag my answer.